# React Use memo does not update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a todo list. I moved the todolist use memo, so that it updates only when todo is added, but ui does not seem to reflect

```html
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <TodoList />
    </div>
  );
}

const Todo = ({ taskName }) => {
  console.log("in here todo");
  return <div>{taskName}</div>;
};

const TodoList = () => {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = React.useState([]);
  const [iptValue, setIptValue] = React.useState("");
  const todoWrapper = React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <>
        {(todoList || []).map((item) => (
          <Todo taskName={item} key={item} />
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }, [todoList]);
  return (
    <div>
      {todoWrapper}
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(ev) => {
          setIptValue(ev.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const todoArr = todoList;
          todoArr.push(iptValue);
          setIptValue("");
          setTodoList(todoArr);
        }}
      >
        Add Notes
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

codepen link: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-cloud-phuxsk?file=/src/App.js:0-1082

Comment: Calling `setTodoList(todoArr);` with same array in terms of `reference` will not trigger a rerender. You need to replace `const todoArr = todoList;` with `const todoArr = [...todoList];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## React's `useMemo` does a shallow comparison via `Object.is`

According to [React's documentation for `useMemo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo),

> React will compare each dependency with its previous value using the `Object.is` comparison.

And according to [the MDN Web Docs for `Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is), it determines whether its arguments are the same. One of the rules is that if "both the same object (meaning both values reference the same object in memory)" then the object is the same.

In your code you are calling `setTodoList(todoArr)` and `todoArr` is a reference to `todoList`. The only change you make to `todoArr` is the call to `todoArr.push`. This does not make a new reference in memory though. This simply modifies `todoList` and `todoArr` because they are one in the same.

### Create a new array

What you need to do is create a new array and then call `setTodoList`. You can also use a library like Immer or Immutable.js to allow you to "modify" arrays and objects and get back a new copy instead.

```
// Vanilla React solution
<button
  onClick={() => {
    const todoArr = [...todoList, iptValue]; // Makes a new copy of the array and appends iptValue
    setTodoList(todoArr);
    setIptValue("");
  }}
>
  Add Notes
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be unrelated but I just notice that the update pattern is incorrect either, when a new state is based/related with it's original value, it should be set [via a callback function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state):

```js
// onClick
() => {
    setIptValue("");
    setTodoList((todoList) => {
        const todoArr = [...todoList];
        todoArr.push(iptValue);
        return todoList
    })
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that the update pattern is incorrect. While you can use a callback as is shown in the React documentation you linked to. The documentation is clearly referring to a circumstance where you want to update one piece of state multiple times. They also have a whole page on this: https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates